# Словарь со вложенным списком

Tags: python, list, словари

имеется словарь с такими значениями
`date = {'Apples': [88, 11],'Bananas': [35, 11],'Grapes': [28, 4]}`
В пустую строку `str_date` надо записать такой вывод словаря
`s_date = "Apples 88 11\n Bananas 35 11\n Grapes 28 4`

Пробовал использовать `join()` и `format()`, но к сожалению не получилось
`s_date = "\n".join(format(k, str(date[k][0]) + " " + str(date[k][1]))for k in date)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот такой вариант правильно обработает любое количество элементов в списке:

```
s_date = "\n".join(" ".join([k]+list(map(str, date[k]))) for k in date)
```

или

```
s_date = "\n".join(f"{k} {' '.join(map(str, date[k]))}" for k in date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас более-менее современный питон, то проще и понятнее использовать `f-строки`:

```
s_date = "\n".join(f'{k} {date[k][0]} {date[k][1]}' for k in date)
```